# How to write jUnit test case for method with private variable

Tags: java, junit, private

```
    private PreconfigGroupOpenLPolicyRulesService openlApi;

@Override
public Object[] getPackageEligibility(IRulesRuntimeContext context, Dimension dimension) {
    return openlApi.PackageEligibility(context, dimension);
}
```

I am new to jUnits. Can anyone help me to write test case for method getPackageEligibility. Which are all i need to do @Mock.

i tried

```
PreconfigGroupOpenLComponentService preconfigGroupOpenLComponentService = new PreconfigGroupOpenLComponentService();

@Mock
PreconfigGroupOpenLPolicyRulesService openlApi;
@Mock
IRulesRuntimeContext context;
@Mock
Dimension dimension;



@Test
public void testGetPackageEligibility() {

    Object[] arg = preconfigGroupOpenLComponentService.getPackageEligibility(context, dimension);
    assertNotNull(arg);

}
```

But getting

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.exigen.eis.preconfig.policy.group.services.impl.PreconfigGroupOpenLComponentService.getPackageEligibility(PreconfigGroupOpenLComponentService.java:32)
    at com.exigen.eis.preconfig.policy.group.services.impl.PreconfigGroupOpenLComponentServiceTest.testGetPackageEligibility(PreconfigGroupOpenLComponentServiceTest.java:28)

Comment: Remove `private` modifier and make the method `default = package private`. Then put a test class in the same package, it will have access to this method.

Comment: You need somehow to "inject" the mocked `PreconfigGroupOpenLPolicyRulesService` into the instance of `PreconfigGroupOpenLComponentService` used in the test (maybe mockito `@InjectMock` or some setter)

Comment: First you need to know the boundry of JUnit and Integration test. JUnit should be only limited to test the business logic of your class, not that of your dependent class. In your example `openlApi.PackageEligibility(context, dimension);` is not part of your class. This method should be tested in test class of `PreconfigGroupOpenLPolicyRulesService`. So if you want to test it, you need to mock `PreconfigGroupOpenLPolicyRulesService` class and add a mock return in case `PackageEligibility(context, dimension)` method is called.

Comment: ` @Test
 public void testGetPackageEligibility() {
  Object obj = new Object();
  Mockito.when(openlApi.PackageEligibility(context, dimension)).thenReturn((Object[]) obj);
  assertNotNull(obj);

 }`    i tried it..Still null pointer exception.